# Source command in bash script

Tags: bash, virtualenv, dot-source

I am trying to put a source command in a bash script so that I can quickly set up and use a virtual environment when writing django websites.

I tried the following without much success as my path was not prefixed with the (path) like it does when I simply enter it at the prompt.

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(pwd | cut -d'/' -f5)
source ~/Documents/virtual-env/$current/bin/activate
```

Can anybody help and let me know what I am overlooking?

**EDIT:**

pwd is "example" and the source is:
`"~/Documents/virtual-env/example/bin/activate"`.

After some research I think I need to use something like:
`"source ./script"`

(not working) as I think the environment is created but not esculated to its parent enviroment which I believe is not possible now.

Comment: What is the output of `pwd` from within the script, and what would be the corresponding path that you are trying to source? Show at least one example.

Comment: pwd is "example" and the source is "~/Documents/virtual-env/example/bin/activate". After some research I think I need to use something like "source ./script" (not working) as I think the environment is created but not esculated to its parent enviroment which I believe is not possible now.

Comment: Yeah you can't change the parent environment by running a script (which happens in a child process), you need to source it. But it's still unclear exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Note that you need to source your script for the same reason *it* needs to source, not execute, the `activate` script.

Comment: What does "without much success" mean, exactly? Did you get an error? What are the exact paths involved? It's very difficult to diagnose when we have such limited information.

Comment: I am trying to produce scripts for creating virtual environments and turning them off and on. Idealy I would like to create a directory "mkdir example" move into it "cd example" and then create an environment at "~/Documents/virtual-env/example" from reading the name of the directory I am in. Which I have managed but then some script to activated it as I am tired of typing "source ~/Documents/virtual-env/example/bin/activate"

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
current=$(basename $(pwd))
source ~/Documents/virtual-env/$current/bin/activate
exec bash # Run new interactive shell in the new environment
```

But I recommend to try [virtualenvwarpper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.